# Error: lvalue required as a left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, c, lvalue

For my first program, I'm trying to make a calculator, but I'm getting an error:

Error: lvalue required as a left operand of assignment

Here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/mxdnPGeT

the error is where I say x + y = sum;

Comment: Reverse the operands, use `sum = x+y`.

Comment: Generally, you should include your code in the question rather than linking to pastebin, to ensure that future readers are able to read it. If the code is too long, try to reduce it to a smaller example that exhibits the problem; see http://sscce.org/ for some ideas for doing that. (In this particular case, though, `x + y = sum;` happened to be enough to pinpoint the problem.)

Answer (score 4):

The assignment operator `=` works by assigning whatever is on the right of the operator to the object on the left. So you are attempting to assign the value of `sum`, which is uninitialized, to the value resulting from `x + y`, which you cannot assign to. Looks like you really want to do:

```
sum = x + y;
```

It's not like in maths where the `=` operator just means that the two operands are equal. In C++ (and many programming languages), `=` is assignment. It assigns from the right to the left. Some languages use different characters for the operator precisely to avoid this confusion (like `:=` or `<-`).

Comment: In C, `x + y` doesn't create a temporary object; it just yields a value. I don't *think* it creates a temporary object in C++ either.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following:

```
x + y = sum;
```

What you needed is:

```
sum = x + y;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x + y = sum;
```

This is not valid, `x+y` is not an lvalue: you can't assign to `x+y` because it doesn't have a [storage address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address).

You should invert the order of the operands in the assignment expression:

```
sum = x + y;
```